# Why do erythrocytes have no MHC1 but platelets do?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, hematology, medicine, red-blood-cell

Red blood cells do not have a considerable number of MHC1 through their membranes, and that's explained by them not having a nucleus. But why do platelets have MHC1s if they have no nucleus either? I don't think that lifespan is a good enough explanation since that would mean young red blood cells have MHC1s and old platelets don't, since the latter can last over a week in circulation. Megakaryocytes do have MHC1s, but that means nothing, since red blood cell percursors also have them.

Comment: There's actually a good answer to this on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Ive-always-wondered-why-platelets-do-not-have-MHC-class-1-and-the-other-cells-do-Does-it-have-something-to-do-with-how-a-peptide-is-loaded-on-an-MHC).